# How can I sum value in list of dataframe

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I want to sum values in list that store in dataframe in column path_pair

| session_id | path | path_pair |
| --- | --- | --- |
| T01 | abc | [0.03, 0.09] |
| T02 | def | [0.02, 0.15, 0.26] |

So the result I want to acheive can be replace same column or create a new one it something looks like this:

| session_id | path | path_pair |
| --- | --- | --- |
| T01 | abc | 0.12 |
| T02 | def | 0.43 |

How can I do the script?

Comment: What are these dataframes? pandas dataframes? Also, what have you tried why did it fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply `sum` function to the `path_pair` column:

```
df['path_pair_sum'] = df['path_pair'].apply(sum)
```

Output:

```
  session_id path           path_pair  path_pair_sum
0        T01  abc        [0.03, 0.09]           0.12
1        T02  def  [0.02, 0.15, 0.26]           0.43
```

Answer (score 0):

You can summarize list, and use a list comprehension to work with whole dataframe.

Here's an example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'session_id': ['T01', 'T02'], 'path_pair': [[0.03, 0.09],[0.02, 0.15, 0.26] ] }


df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

df['sum'] = [sum(x) for x in df['path_pair']]
```

You will get a new column with summarized values.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in many ways, one of the ways is the following one:

```
# intialise data of lists.
data = {'Name':['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'],
        'Score':[[20,12], [21,24], [19,34], [18,32]]}
 
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#Sum list in Score and replacing list with sum value
df['Score'] = [sum(x) for x in df['Score']]

# Print the output.
df
```

Sum is done by following code:

> df['Score'] = [sum(x) for x in df['Score']]